# How does IXPE measure polarization, and why does it have three identical X-ray telescopes?

Tags: observational-astronomy, space-telescope, instruments, x-ray

From [The Observatory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60155601#60155601):

> Anyone who missed any of the AAS 239 press conferences can see them on the AAS Press Office's YouTube channel! Here's [the full program](https://aas.org/meetings/aas239/2nd-media-advisory#program).

From there I found the Monday, January 10, 2022 presentation [NASA’S Newest X-Ray Eyes: an Update on the Imaging X-ray Polarimetry Explorer (IXPE)](https://aas.org/sites/default/files/2022-01/AAS239_Mon2_MartinWeisskopf.pdf) by Martin C. Weisskopf, IXPE Principal Investigator NASA/Marshall Space Flight Center

Below is a screenshot from page 4 which shows a diagram of IXPE and indicates that it has three parallel and identical X-ray telescopes.

**Question:** How does IXPE measure polarization, and why does it have **three** identical X-ray telescopes?

[image: cropped from slide #4 of Martin C. Weisskopf, IXPE Principal Investigator's NASA’S Newest X-Ray Eyes: an Update on the Imaging X-ray Polarimetry Explorer (IXPE)]

Comment: @PM2Ring ya it seems to have been the result of an edit gone wrong; the current answer's author didn't catch it either, so I've deleted the first "telescope" in all places on the page (except of course your comment. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How does IXPE measure polarization?**

Short answer: Electrons in the detector are preferential emitted in the direction of the polarization of the incident photon and then detected.

Quoting from NASA's [IXPE: Polarization Detection](https://ixpe.msfc.nasa.gov/detectors.html) page:

> IXPE will have three identical X-ray telescopes, with polarization
> detectors at each focus. The detectors, called Gas Pixel Detectors
> (GPD) are based on proportional counters (see [Mullard Space Science
> Laboratory's Introduction to Proportional Counters](http://www.mssl.ucl.ac.uk/%7Emwt/propcounters/intro.htm)). Polarized X rays
> interacting with a gaseous medium create photoelectons that are
> preferentially emitted in the polarization direction. Photoelectron
> tracks mark the path of the photoelectron from the position of the
> initial X-ray interaction to its stopping point. Analysis of the
> distribution of the initial directions of the tracks gives the degree
> of polarization and the position angle from the incident X ray.
> [image: Depiction of polarization selection process in the X-ray detector]

**Why does it have three identical X-ray telescopes?**

Quoting from [IXPE - Satellite Missions - eoPortal Directory](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/ixpe):

Short answer: Redundancy and the three smaller systems could be accommodated better than one larger equivalent telescope.

> These trades were completed and the result is the three telescope
> system described here which meets science objectives and requirements
> with margin while placing reasonable and achievable demands on the
> spacecraft, launch vehicle, and the deployable optical bench.
> Specifically, three identical systems provide redundancy, a range of
> detector clocking angles to mitigate against any detector biases,
> shorter focal length for given mirror graze angles (i.e., given energy
> response) and thinner/lighter mirrors compared to a single telescope
> system.